# Auto suggestion of Feed URL if website name is entered

Tags: php, jquery, rss, feed, rss-reader

I am developing feed Reader using PHP, Mysql, jQuery. I have option for user to enter the feed url or website url.

Now when feed url is entered i dont have any issues, but **when website URL is entered i need to develop something in PHP or jQuery to suggest available feed for that website.**

e.g:- if user enter http://www.cnn.com then i should list all available feed URL on cnn.com to user and let user choose which one he/she want.

Is any buddy have idea or point me to correct resources i can refer to develop such feature in PHP or jQuery.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Mona

Comment: I dont 'think suggesting a feed url is a great idea... because RSS feeds are cryptic. It would be like suggesting an IP address to somebody entering a domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I dont 'think suggesting a feed url is a great idea... because RSS feeds are cryptic. It would be like suggesting an IP address to somebody entering a domain name. When people want to follow cnn.com in your reader, they don't want to follow cnn.com/rss (which they dont care about, but they want to follow "CNN's headlines" (or something like this).

So, in pratice, you should discover these feeds, but rather than exposing their URL, expose their titles. This is orders of magnitude more meaningful and helpful. Also, think about supporting [SubToMe](https://www.subtome.com/#/).